# co-existence of Symfony and wordpress in single webserver

Tags: wordpress, symfony

I have implemented my website in symfony2.4, but my blog in configured and installed in wordpress instance.

my wesite is under /var/www/html/website/ and the DocumentRoot is in httpd.cont is set to /var/www/html/website/web folder of symfony.

my wordpress is installed in /var/www/html/blog - I have created a soft link of the same in Symfony's web folder. But the wordpress site does not seem to work.

is there anything else that i need to configure?

my .htaccess file from sumfony's web folder looks something like this:

```
    enter code here
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
#    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    #RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    #RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    #RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    #RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make the two cohabit with this .htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  #path to symfony
  DocumentRoot "path/web"
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
  DirectoryIndex app.php

  <Directory "/path/web">
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +MultiViews
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  #path to blog
  Alias /blog "/otherpath/blog"
  <Directory /otherpath/blog>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +MultiViews
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```